# Unable to build web interface open-ethereum-pool ubuntu 20.04

Tags: javascript

The open-ethereum-pool web interface stopped building, constantly errors, here is a list of input commands: nvm use v8.17.0
npm install -g ember-cli@2.9.1
npm install -g bower
npm install[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTcrB.png)

nvm use v8.17.0
npm install -g ember-cli@2.9.1
npm install -g bower
npm install[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiqRc.png)